# create an expression referencing full table without having access to the context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

My model classes are strictly separated from the context instance and have no knowledge of the context instance.

Every query is driven by expressions like `Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>` which are `OR` and `AND` combined using `PredicateBuilder` (LinqKit). The expressions are created once (context agnostic) and executed later on different threads against newly created contexts (`DbContext` derived class).

This works well for dozens of expressions. But I have **no idea** how I would reference other tables which are not accessible by navigation properties:

Working sample (if I had a context variable):

```
using(var context = new MyEntities())
{
    Expression<Func<Entity1, bool>> filter = e1 =>
        context.Set2.Any(e2 => e2.Data.StartsWith(e1.Prefix));

    var result = context.Set1.Where(filter).ToList();
}
```

But I have to create the expression **before** the context is constructed and so have no access to `context.Set2`.

### Question

Does there exist another syntax for replacing `context.Set2`, maybe like `DbSet<Entity2>.All` or `Queryable<Entity2>.All` or something similar, which does not require a context instance?

Using navigation properties I already can create expressions with joins to other tables which can result in KBs of SQL code without ever needing a reference to a context instance -- so I see absolutely no point why a context instance should be needed at all now.

I already tried using a "fake" null instance but this throws a NullException:

```
protected override Expression<Func<Entity1, bool>> BuildFilter()
{
    MyEntities fake = null;
    return e1 => fake.Set2.Any(e2 => e2.Data.StartsWith(e1.Prefix));
}
```

Comment: Is it an option to prepare expression factories instead of expressions? And only create a actual expressions after creating a context instance? For example you could have a factory that given a `IQueryable<T>`instance, gives you back a specific expression?

Comment: @YacoubMassad I'm sure that would work (and I already thought about that before posting the question) but that would affect a huge class and interface hierarchy which I would like to prevent if there is another simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Answering myself / The way I will try to go**

Since I'm already using PredicateBuilder/LinqKit I will pass the context via parameter into the expression itself and expand it when I really have a context instance -- pretests in LinqPad performed fine so far:

```
Expression<Func<MyEntities, Entity1, bool>> filterTemplate = (ctx, e1) =>
    ctx.Set2.Any(e2 => e2.Data.StartsWith(e1.Prefix));

using(var context = new MyEntities())
{
    Expression<Func<Entity1, bool>> filter = e1 =>
        filterTemplate.Invoke(context, e1); // .Invoke() -> LinqKit

    var result = context.Set1.Where(filter.Expand()).ToList(); // .Expand() -> LinqKit

    // or
    var result = context.Set1.AsExpandable().Where(filter).ToList(); // .AsExpandable() -> LinqKit
}
```

At least at the producer side class hierarchy I could introduce this in a non-breaking way, so the existing 1000 expressions don't have to be changed and only the 1001th expression is created by the new method:

**before**

```
    protected abstract Expression<Func<Entity1, bool>> BuildFilter();
```

**after**

```
    protected virtual Expression<Func<Entity1, bool>> BuildFilter()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException($"Either {nameof(this.BuildFilter)} or {nameof(this.BuildFilter2)} has to be overridden!");
    }

    protected virtual Expression<Func<MyEntities, Entity1, bool>> BuildFilter2()
    {
        var legacyFilter = this.BuildFilter();
        Expression<Func<MyEntities, Entity1, bool>> result = (context, e1) => legacyFilter.Invoke(e1);
        return result.Expand();
    }
```